# Is it possible to change the color of a range based on the value of a single cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
    function addConditionalFormatting(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("G3");
  var Master = sheet.getRange("G2:J6")
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenTextEqualTo("Female")
    .setBackground("#25ABE2")
    .setRanges([Master])
    .build();
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

The idea is for the range to change colors based on cell G3 which has a data validation list with 3 choices: Male, Female, and Unisex. Currently I am only trying to change the color of 1 before I add more rules but I am unable to make it work.

Im unsure where to apply the variable "range"

Is it possible to change the color of a range based on the value of a single cell?

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: Yes, this is possible :)

Try this -

```
function addConditionalFormatting(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
//  var range = sheet.getRange("G3");
  var Master = sheet.getRange("G2:J6")
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$G$3="Female"')
  .setBackground("#25ABE2")
  .setRanges([Master])
  .build();
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

I've replaced `.whenTextEqualTo("Female")` with `.whenFormulaSatisfied('=$G$3="Female"')` and also commented out the `var range = sheet.getRange("G3")` (not sure if it was being used for something else though).

How did I solve this?

1. I first tried doing this on the sheet without the script using the actual UI; **Format > Conditional formatting** and chose 'Custom formula is' instead of 'Text is exactly' (had to study [Example 2 from this article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413)
2. Recorded the whole process again using a macro ;) i.e. **Tools > Macros > Record macro**

Hope this helps but please feel free to write back in case you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set an actual conditional format on the range beforehand? Why do you wanna do this via app script? Seems like a huge workaround. [Here a gif to set that up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDZCh.gif)